# Unable to check for updates on windows phone 8.1, error code 80072efd

Tags: 8.1, 8.1-update-1

Whenever I try to update my Windows Phone I face an 80072efd (check for updates) error. How can I resolve this update error?

Error Message:

> we are currently unable to check for updates (80072efd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason on **windows phone website**:

> **80072efd** - There was a temporary issue with a server or your Internet connection during the update.
>
> Make sure you're connected to the Internet and try again. It's best to connect to WiFi so you can avoid possible mobile data charges.

Not Only **80072efd** error code, but if you face **following any error code** same problem (There was a temporary issue with a server or your Internet connection during the update. ),

#### unable to check for updates error Code:

```
801881d0
8018822a
80072f30
80072ee7
80072ee2
80072efd   --- I face this
80072f76
80072efe
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this is a pretty generic error.

I suspect it is this one:
ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT
which is error 12029 on this page of windows http errors

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383770%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

How did I get to this error...

Well like most windows error codes if you split them in half you get 8007 2efd, generally the first half indicates what in windows gave an error (8007 are windows general errors[1]) the second half is the error code.

Converting from Hex to Decimal using the Windows calculator gives us an error code of 12029 following on from that doing a google search with "12029 +site:msdn.microsoft.com" to narrow the results down to the msdn library and it's a pretty good bet this is the correct area to be looking in.

Finally I find I get major problems if the time on the phone has drifted to far from real world time with all sorts of third party services. (authentication fails etc)

[1] Other codes are 8020 (BITS - background intelligent transfer service often used to download windows updates), 8019 are http errors there is a list in winerror.h in the windows SDK but again you'll need to translate from decimal to hex after masking the error flag off.